# how to extract an array into varriable

Tags: php, arrays

i have an API which responds with an array. i need to extract individual array values(postions) into varriable. can any one help

```
       {"response":{"referenceId":"emma-1018-0706462482","Id":"102235946","status":"Success"}}
```

Comment: have you tried foreach function?

Comment: Looks like it's json. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: it's not array.it's json. decode it and get your array. just use json_decode()

Comment: read what @aynber post. First decode the response from the server and later you can use foreach to get in every element in the array. Olso when using json decode, do it this way-> $array = json_decode($response, true)

Comment: https://eval.in/646951